# change of value on selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider containing of two images. I have split them into two classes : `item active` and `item`. i also have a dropdown selection box where I can select the color. Depending on the selection I would like to show the selected color.

The first class:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="product-image image">
        <img src="http://www.aaa.aa/image1" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

The second class:

```
<div class="item active">
    <div class="product-image image">
        <img src="http://aaaa.aa/mage2" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

DropDown Menu

```
<div class="input-select input-select--alternate">
    <select data-choosetxt="Colour" name="super_attribute[124]" id="attribute124" class="validate-select super-attribute-select validation-passed" data-role="none">
        <option value="">Selection1</option>
        <option value="473" price="0">Selection2</option>
        <option value="475" price="0">Selection3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Read about the CSS `:target` selector, I hope this is what you're looking for. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp

Comment: @odedta I wanted to visualise different image based on the selection from the dropdown. Any ideas how can this be achieved? Regards

Comment: Have you written any Javascript/jQuery code to accompany this?

Comment: OMG, I just found out that `:target` selector doesn't work on `select` tag options. Interesting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576563/target-selector-doesnt-work-with-option-tags

Answer (score 1):

I personally would restruct your html differently.  But here is a simple example of changing something with JS and JQUERY.  Link to JS FIddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/f8kzmm0t/

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="product-image image">
        <img src="http://www.aaa.aa/image1" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item active">
    <div class="product-image image">
        <img src="http://aaaa.aa/mage2" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="input-select input-select--alternate">
    <select data-choosetxt="Colour" name="super_attribute[124]" id="attribute124" class="validate-select super-attribute-select validation-passed" data-role="none">
        <option value="">Selection1</option>
        <option value="473" price="0">Selection2</option>
        <option value="475" price="0">Selection3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( "#attribute124" ).change(function() {
    var curr = $( "#attribute124" ).val();

    if(curr == ''){
        alert('do something');
    }else if(curr == '473'){
        alert('change color here');
    }else if(curr == 475){
        alert('change color here');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.item{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
.item.active{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Tweak the above to get your desired result.