# :target selector doesn't work with option tags

Tags: html, css

I tried to help a fellow StackOverflow member here and I found out that the CSS `:target` selector doesn't work with option tags. I have created an example to illustrate using [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_target), the code is this:

```css
:target {
    border: 2px solid #D4D4D4;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option><a href="#image1">This doesn't work!</a></option>
    <option><a href="#image2">Selection2</a></option>
    <option><a href="#image3">Selection3</a></option>
</select>

<p><a href="#image1">This Works!</a></p>

<div id="image1">1</div>
<div id="image2">2</div>
<div id="image3">3</div>
```

Any idea why? am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<option>` tag only must have text inside, so what happens is that browser ignore the other tags, and show only the text. You can inspect the rendered HTML and you can see what I am saying. In this case this render as:

```
<select>
    <option>This doesn't work!</option>
    <option>Selection2</option>
    <option>Selection3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because option doesn't allow other elements in it.

Only solution is with Javascript i guess/